# How to refactor these classes to interact each other?

Tags: oop, loose-coupling, cohesion

My **requirement** is to use the name of the *shape* and draw that shape with the *dimensions* like in the method `Draw('rectangle', 'l:10,w:20');`.

1. There should be validation of the dimensions against the type of the shape.
2. These classes can be refactored to add more classes or change the hierarchy.
3. No run-time checking like *reflection* should be used. The problem needs to be solved with class design only.
4. Don't use `if-else` or `switch` statements in the client method `Draw`.

Requirement:

```
public static void main()
{
    // Provide the shape and it's dimensions
    Draw('rectangle', 'l:10,w:20');
    Draw('circle', 'r:15');
}
```

I created the following classes. I considered *low(loose) coupling and high cohesion* by making two class hierarchies so they can grow on it's own. I kept the responsibilities of drawing to one class and generating the dimension to the other class.

My question is about creating these objects and interacting each other to achieve my requirements.

```
public abstract class Shape()
{
    Dimension dimension;
    public void abstract SetDimentions(Dimension dimension);
    public void abstract Draw()
}

public void Rectangle()
{
    void override SetDimensions(RectangleDimension dimension)
    {
    }

    void override Draw()
    {
        // Use the 'dimention' to draw
    }
}

public void Circle()
{
    void override SetDimensions(CircleDimension dimension)
    {
    }

    void override Draw()
    {
        // Use the 'dimention' to draw
    }
}

public class RectangleDimension
{
    public int length {get; set; }
    public int width { get; set; }
}

public class CircleDimension
{
    public int circle { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use reflection in whatever OOP technology you are using. You receive a `String` like `"circle"` and you need to call a method with that name.

This is how you can do that in [Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/methodInvocation.html) and this is how you can do it in [C#](https://www.dotnetperls.com/getmethod).

Comment: I can't use reflection. The class hierarchy can be modified or new classes can be added.

Comment: @wonderfulworld then you can check the string value with if-else conditions and in each case call the corresponding method.

Comment: Can you explain with code? I'm trying to avoid ```if-else``` and ```switch``` statements.

Comment: @wonderfulworld the purpose of using reflection was to avoid if-elses. Without reflection you will need something like if (shapeName.equals("circle")) {Draw("circle", params)}; else {/*...*/} and you have shapeName and params as the parameter of Draw.